# Running PHP/MySQL on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, mysql, php

I have a client that has a fairly basic web ordering system that was built for them many years ago. It is based on runs fine on PHP 5.3.

Now, it connects to a (even older) warehouse management system (a Microsoft FoxPro database) through an ODBC bridge (Easysoft). The server itself is a VPS Centos 5 server running MySQL and Apache, with 1.5GB memory and 2 CPU cores). I have reason to believe that this server is grossly under-powered and is largely contributing to the performance issues we have been having lately.

I have to somehow come up with a way to address the performance issue without having to spend too much money. I solution I have come up with involves moving the server to a Windows 2008 R2 server, and I am wanting your opinions on this:

- If I move the server to the same server as the database is on, then the ODBC bridge will no longer be needed. Currently, this freezes up every now and then and I believe this has something to do with the performance issues.
- The Windows Server currently has 8GB of memory and 4CPU Cores and is not overly stressed.

My questions:

- Does PHP run fine on Windows 2008 these days? I understand that is wasn't really designed for Windows, but for such a basic PHP site, should it suffice (when I say basic, I say that in terms of it not relying on a framework or any other classes- it is pure PHP code with some ODBC function calls).
- How does MySQL go on Windows?
- If I was to go this route, should I use apache or IIS?

Any advice appreciated. I know the best solution is probably to upgrade the Centos server, however for an extra 2GB of memory, it will cost my client $160 per month, which for a small business is not small change.

Answer (score 1):

My personal experience with windows implementations of PHP/MySQL have resulted in pain for me, my employees, and my customers.

1. I have found many memory leaks and performance issues with PHP in 2008R2.
2. MySQL uses a huge amount of memory in Windows.
3. Security updates for exploits do not come as fast for windows if at all.

In your situation I would seriously consider Windows 2008R2 with your LAMP in Hyper-V. I have found my Hyper-V processes for my LAMP servers to be very CPU and memory efficient.